# python2.7.10,OSX(10.11.2)でCarbon.Evt.EventAvailが見つからない。

Tags: python

python 2.7.10を使ってOSX(10.11.2)で
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892/
を参考にOSXでgetch()を実装しようとしたのですが、

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'EventAvail'
というエラーが出てきます。

具体的なコードは下記の通りです。

```
from Carbon import  Evt

class _Getch:
    def __init__(self):
        import Carbon,Carbon.Evt
        Carbon.Evt

    def __call__(self):
        import Carbon
        if Evt.EventAvail(0x0008)[0]==0: # 0x0008 is the keyDownMask
            return ''
        else:
            (what,msg,when,where,mod)=Carbon.Evt.GetNextEvent(0x0008)[1]
            return chr(msg & 0x000000FF)

getch = _Getch()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/carbon.html#module-Carbon.Evt
マニュアルによると

> Most of the OS X APIs that these modules use are deprecated or removed
>   in recent versions of OS X.

とのことで、使えなさそうです。コンソールで良いなら、次のようにselectを使えば、リアルタイム入力ができます。

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import select
import tty
import termios

def main():
    while True:
        print "hit ESC key"
        r, w, e = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)
        if r and r[0] is sys.stdin:
            if r[0].read(1) == '\x1b':
                break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    term_settings = termios.tcgetattr(sys.stdin)
    try:
        tty.setcbreak(sys.stdin.fileno())
        main()
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(sys.stdin, termios.TCSADRAIN, term_settings)
```